# AWS S3: You have attempted to create more buckets than allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm aware 100 s3 bucket is the soft limit and we can increase it to 1000 create a request. but my issue is
earlier I had 100 buckets, but I deleted some of them and now its is 90. But even after this, I'm recieving same error.

Comment: It takes up to a few hours until the buckets are fully deleted, try again in a bit. It's the same problem with bucket names, you can't re-use them immediately after you've deleted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Maurice comment solve the problem. AWS can take time to remove the buckets